# Is there any uniform way of creating custom comparator in c++?

Tags: c++

Basically I need a way to create comparator in a uniform manner for comparing in `sort()` function and priority queue. It will be easier to remember also.

My doubt is why the priority queue is using "Comp" and sort is using "Comp()". Is there any other way so that both can use the same format?
Kindly tell some standard way. Thanks.

I am trying to compare the class in this question 
: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimum-platforms/0 .

Code : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/R8snxdJl1B .

[Link for below code](http://cpp.sh/4vty).

```
// constructing priority queues
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <queue>          // std::priority_queue
#include <vector>         // std::vector
#include <functional>     // std::greater
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Comp{
public:
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int&rhs) const{
    return (lhs>rhs);
  }
};

int main (){
  int myints[]= {10,60,50,20};

  // using mycomparison:
  priority_queue<int, vector<int>, Comp> pq;
  cout << "pq is using mycomparison" << endl;

  vector<int> v= {10,60,50,20};
  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Comp());
  cout << "sort using mycomparison()" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One is a type and the other is an instance.

Comment: The question is, I guess, is there any way to change the code so both parts require a class, or both require an instance. I don't know how to answer that; would be nice to see answers.

Comment: Rough rule of thumb: If it's in angle brackets, it's `Comp`, otherwise it's `Comp()`. But I would suggest not trying to hide away (or rather hiding away from) as much of the language as you can (like you did with `using namespace std;`), it will soon limit you.

Comment: You already have what you want.  You can't do `Comp()` in `priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>, Comp>` because that expects a type and you can't do `Comp` in `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Comp());` because that expects an object.

Comment: The two answers (at the time of writing) are both correct, and IMO each one makes the original code look better by comparison. You have to learn the difference between a type and an object some time, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why the priority queue is using "Comp" and sort is using "Comp()"

`priority_queue` is a type, `sort` is a function. Functions can infer template arguments, but default-constructed types have no arguments to infer types from.

If you call the constructor, the template deduction guides from C++17 will let you use the `Comp()` form:

```
std::priority_queue pq{Comp(), std::vector<int>()};
```

If you only have C++11 or 14, you can write a helper function to build one with a custom comparator:

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>, typename Comp>
std::priority_queue<T, Container, Comp> make_priority_queue(Comp comp) {
    return std::priority_queue<T, Container, Comp>{comp};
}
```

used as

```
auto pq = make_priority_queue<int>(Comp());
```

Comment: An important distinction to make in this case, I think, is that for `priority_queue` the comparator to use is a property of the type itself, whereas for `std::sort` it's a property of the operation. That is, a `priority_queue<T, C<T>, Comp1>` is fundamentally different from a `priority_queue<T, C<T>, Comp2>` because their sort orders differ. But for `std::sort` the comparator type doesn't really matter, because the sort order is determined by the concrete instance you pass in.

Comment: Ok, sort(...) can take Object but priority queue can not because it's a data type . That helps to remember at least .But there has to be some simpler way . Thanks .

Comment: This really helps to remember that sort can take object Comp(). Thank you again .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a homespun functor, use a lambda instead. They're much simpler, and they work for both. Any further differences in syntax are just how `std::sort` and `std::priority_queue` were designed. But, you never have to remember `Comp()` vs. `Comp`.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <array>
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <queue>     // std::priority_queue
#include <vector>    // std::vector

int main() {
  // Lambda instead of functor
  constexpr auto Comp = [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) { return lhs > rhs; };

  // std::array as an iterable type for priority_queue
  std::array<int, 4> myints = {10, 60, 50, 20};

  // using mycomparison:
  // As someone else stated, you can leave all this template stuff out in C++17
  // std::priority_queue pq(Comp, myints);
  std::priority_queue<int, decltype(myints), decltype(Comp)> pq(Comp, myints);
  std::cout << "pq is using mycomparison" << std::endl;

  std::vector<int> v = {10, 60, 50, 20};
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Comp);
  std::cout << "sort using mycomparison()" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I also removed the `using namespace std;` line as that's a bad practice. If you don't like all the `std::` stuff, you can use `using` statements instead.

```
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
// etc.
```

[Link](http://cpp.sh/32zwn)

Comment: Thanks for telling a best practice for using "using std::cout; using std::vector" . I am doing this problem https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/GclreNs0e6 . Is it possible to extend your solution to my problem where Comparator can take class as a argument ?

Comment: That lambda will already compare *any* two types that can be compared with the `>` operator. Also, your link just takes me to some code, not a problem statement.